# Web App that polls phone gps location, shows compass toward second stationary point

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, web, gps

Aspersonal pet project as a newbie programmer, I'm Looking to make a webapp to poll gps data on an iPhone, and then calculate the distance to a predetermined point.   Then  use the haversine formula to calculate/update the distance.  I would also like to have a compass show the direction of the stationary point on the iPhone.   What would be the easiest way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've searched for geolocation for iOS. Keyword will be CoreLocation (a native library you will import into your app. This gives you out of the box ability to get GPS coords for your current location.

By "predetermined point" I'm assuming you are hitting up some database of stored locations (i.e. the supermarket, bar xyz, etc?). Just a matter of figuring out how you will poll this.

Now you've got your two pairs of coordinates (where I am / where I'm going to). Plenty of mapping apis out there to fiddle around with, with the math already baked in. :) Good luck.